# Union of tables without repeating conditions

Tags: sql

I have three tables A, B, C.
A and B have the same structure, i.e. the same columns and already a distinct key. What I want to do is unify A and B, and then join the union with C. I know I can do this in this way:

```
(SELECT x FROM A INNER JOIN C ON y WHERE z) 
UNION 
(SELECT x FROM B INNER JOIN C ON y WHERE z)
```

However, then I have to repeat the conditions which is very inconvenient to me, especially when the query gets longer and needs to be adjusted frequently.

If I do the union inside, then the query does not complete for me at all (may be it just takes unbearably long)

```
SELECT y
FROM (SELECT * FROM A UNION SELECT * FROM B) U
INNER JOIN C on y
WHERE z
```

Is there a more elegant, efficient way of doing this without repetitions?

I use SAP SQL.

Comment: So if your filter on each statement filter out 90% of the data, you will rather not do it because it's inconvenient???  It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: While A and B may have appropriate indexes that help with the join, these indexes can no longer be used `UNION`, i.e. the unioned result does not have indexes. All the DBMS can do then is read this result set sequentially. So, for the join you need a helpful index on table C. Make sure you have an index on all the columns you join on.

Comment: What is z? Restrictions on A/B or restrictions on C or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the query doesn't complete the second time, is that by `union`-ing, you lose all context and statistics about the table, it isn't able to use indexes, and thus has to fall back on slower methods.

It sounds like the first option is your only one, but you might be able to use a `VIEW` to prevent you from having to type the same thing over and over. See [their documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cc2b23beaa3344aebffa2f6e717df049/2.0.02/en-US/7b1ddcdb650c44308f5bf6339ed9b4b2.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

This should work pretty well if your columns don't have duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x
FROM ((SELECT *
       FROM A INNER JOIN 
            C
            ON y 
      ) 
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT *
       FROM B INNER JOIN
            C
            ON y
      )
     ) abc
WHERE z;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon I will try that. Is the second 'SELECT x' correct or should it be 'SELECT *'?

Comment: @HaukeL. . . . It should be `select *`.  Actually, you should just select the columns you need for the conditions.